# Getting the Plaid Link to Work in my Create React App with Auth0

Tags: create-react-app, auth0, plaid

I had started a project a little while ago and have been busy lately so I have not been able to work on it. I am out of practice with web development because I had recently joined the military. Right now the project consists of a create-react-app app with auth0 integrated. What I am trying to do is get the plaid link integrated into the page it takes you after logging in using auth0. I am requesting help on what code from the plaid docs I use in order for this to work. Their documentation is a little confusing to me, maybe because I'm so out of practice. Any help would be much much appreciated.

https://github.com/CollinChiz/SeeMyCash

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Quickstart at https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/? It contains a full React implementation that does this. Here's the relevant excerpt:

```
// APP COMPONENT
// Upon rendering of App component, make a request to create and
// obtain a link token to be used in the Link component
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { usePlaidLink } from 'react-plaid-link';
const App = () => {
  const [linkToken, setLinkToken] = useState(null);
  const generateToken = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/create_link_token', {
      method: 'POST',
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    setLinkToken(data.link_token);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    generateToken();
  }, []);
  return linkToken != null ? <Link linkToken={linkToken} /> : <></>;
};
// LINK COMPONENT
// Use Plaid Link and pass link token and onSuccess function
// in configuration to initialize Plaid Link
interface LinkProps {
  linkToken: string | null;
}
const Link: React.FC<LinkProps> = (props: LinkProps) => {
  const onSuccess = React.useCallback((public_token, metadata) => {
    // send public_token to server
    const response = fetch('/api/set_access_token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ public_token }),
    });
    // Handle response ...
  }, []);
  const config: Parameters<typeof usePlaidLink>[0] = {
    token: props.linkToken!,
    onSuccess,
  };
  const { open, ready } = usePlaidLink(config);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => open()} disabled={!ready}>
      Link account
    </button>
  );
};
export default App;
```